# Angular. How to bind typing text?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to bind typing text from text area (child component) to parent component and call it onclick. button is included in parent component?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Input() variableName: string = '';
@Output() variableNameChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

without any forms & reactive forms:

```
<textarea [value]="variableName" (keyup)="variableNameChange.emit($event.target.value)">
```

or with forms:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="variableName" (ngModelChange)="variableNameChange.emit(variableName)">
```